# NodeJs/Mongoose - Unable to find data from an Object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User collection in a mongo DB, it has a company field that is a reference to another collection called Company.
I assign the company to the user. and when i try to print the data inside the company field it returns me : undefined.

this is the code that i use,

```
console.log('company: ' + req.user.company); 
if(req.user.company) 
   console.log("LOGGED IN USER" + "\n Email:" + req.user.username + "\n Psw: " + req.user.password + "\n Role: " + req.user.role + "\n Company: " + req.user.company.name);
```

and this is the response on the terminal:

```
company: 59aab09745db5532c4321742
LOGGED IN USER
 Email:user@admin.com
 Psw: $2a$10$Z7h3ikaDJLhLXMotV.odaerGf5RFRXxDmlVxCFdvTaL48WalNIwRy
 Role: admin
 Company: undefined
```

as you can see the first terminal line shows the company id assigned to that particular user, but when i try to print the name of that company it returns undefined.

this is the Company collection entry, it has the name field and the object id is the same as i print above

[image]

where am i wrong?
if you need further informations please let me know
thank you

Comment: *"where am i wrong?"* How would we know? There is no code here performing the query. That's actually the only code you needed to show us and it's not even here.\

Comment: @NeilLunn If you pay attention, he is printing `req.user.company` and it is shown as the ObjectId, not the object itself. He is not populating that field. I think it is pretty obvious, even though the code is not explicit.

Comment: Your comment said: `here because if it was an issue of a missing "populate" then the field reference value would be there and not undefined`. It is there, look at his code `company: 59aab09745db5532c4321742`. Are you blind or just tilted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to populate the company.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

When you print:

```
console.log('company: ' + req.user.company);
```

It shows:

```
company: 59aab09745db5532c4321742
```

So your `req.user.company` is not the object you expect to be, but the string of the `_id` of the object. So it must be populated.

When you use something like `User.findOne({...})` you have to append the population like this:

```
User.findOne({...}).populate("company");
```

References to objects are stored as strings containing the ObjectId of the referenced document. If you want the reference not to be the string, but the object it is referencing, you have to do it this way.

Comment: Just pay attention to his code. He printed company, being an string and not an object. This is an obvious problem of not populating that field. I don't see what's wrong with my assumption. Undefined is not the value of `req.user.company` but the value of `req.user.company.whatever` because `req.user.company` is an string.

Comment: @NeilLunn And you gave a downvote because you don't understand my point, and you don't see you are wrong. Hilarious.

Comment: I gave you a downvote because `undefined` simply is the result of the referenced input value not being defined. Nothing to do with populate and no attempt at a "query" being shown in the question at all. Ignorance and bad attitude are just bonus reasons really

Comment: @NeilLunn I edited the answer btw so you can see the point because you are missing it totally from the question.